# How do I create new subdirectories/folders withing my app bundle during runtime?

Tags: iphone, subdirectory

I am writing many files to disk, and I would like to split them up into different categories, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following methods in `NSFileManager` class:

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

Note also that you cannot write anything into application **bundle**. Application sandbox however contains several folders where you can write (the choice between them depends on your needs). See ["Commonly Used Directories"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW12) for more information.